# Linking checkboxes in a form back to a string property of a class in MVC/Razor Pages

Tags: c, forms, model-view-controller, razor-pages, tempdb

I am creating a form for an assignment where when the form is completed the data entered for each applicant is saved to a DB. Each property for the applicants is created in a Applicant class, some are required some not.

As part of this I need to ask the user to enter the gender of the applicant. What I had initially thought to do and implement was create a checkbox for each gender in my form and dependent on which one is checked in my page model I then save that gender back to the Gender property of my Applicant.cs which is a string. When the OnPost() is run.

This works fine but the Gender property must be Required and when I set the prop to Required in the class and run the application, when I try to submit the form I get an error on the page stating the Gender is required.

What is the best way for me to code this in this case or should I think about an alternative solution altogether? I know I could just get the user to type in the gender in a text box and it will work but I thought a group of checkboxes would be neater.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user to make one choice from a very limited number of options, the best control is the `input type="radio"`. This also has the benefit of working well with Razor Pages validation.

Here is your `PageModel` property:

```
[BindProperty, Required]
public string Gender { get; set; }
```

And here is your form:

```
<span asp-validation-for="Gender"></span>
<form method="post">
    <input type="radio" asp-for="Gender" value="Male" />Male<br />
    <input type="radio" asp-for="Gender" value="Female" />Female<br />
    <input type="radio" asp-for="Gender" value="Other" />Other<br />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: That is perfect, thanks very much, not sure why I had decided on the checkbox. I'm a total beginner at this stuff!!!
It might require a new question but if I had a longer list where the user could select more than 1 option what would be the best way to do that? I tried with a list but the DB doesnt like me trying to add that to it.